# How do you use the heap package in Go?

Tags: go, package, heap, priority-queue

I've been trying to use the Heap package in Go and I am not sure on how to initialize it.

```
package main
import "container/heap"

type PriorityMessage struct {
    Priority int
    Message string
}

func priorityQueue() {
    //WOULD THIS not initialize the heap?
    h := heap.Init(h PriorityMessage)

}
```

I've been trying to find examples online of how other's initialized their heaps and all of them seem to create their own versions of the Go heap package everytime. Would calling the heap.Init(h Interface) function from the heap package not work?

Comment: See the [example in the documentation](https://godoc.org/container/heap#example-package--PriorityQueue).

Comment: That's what I was confused about, just like how in this example how they create the push, pop, len .etc functions, every time you wanted to use a heap would you have to write those functions as well or could you just call it from the heap package?

Comment: See the [Interface](https://godoc.org/container/heap#Interface) documentation.  The application provides simple operations for accessing the underlying data.  The heap package uses those operations to implement heap semantics.

Comment: @paartrk Yes, of course.

Comment: You can see the usage of `container/heap` package in this post along with some example usage: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/usage-of-the-heap-data-structure-in-go-golang-with-examples

Answer (score 6):

There is the heap.Interface what you should implement first.

```
type Interface interface {
    sort.Interface
    Push(x interface{}) // add x as element Len()
    Pop() interface{}   // remove and return element Len() - 1.
}
```

This means you should have the necessary methods for your PriorityMessage struct. After you pass the instance of the struct into the heap.Init(&pm).

You can find details in the [godoc](https://godoc.org/container/heap#example-package--PriorityQueue) as linked in the comments.

Just to clarify the confusion. Go is a strongly typed language with lack of generics. So the heap package designed on the way that it's type independent. You can create your own implementation for all of the types what you want to implement. Any type implements the heap.Interface can be used by the heap package.

Answer (score 4):

```
  //https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/container/heap/example_intheap_test.go 
    
    // This example demonstrates an integer heap built using the heap interface.
    //package heap_test
    
    import (
        "container/heap"
        "fmt"
    )
    
    // An IntHeap is a min-heap of ints.
    type IntHeap []int
    
    func (h IntHeap) Len() int           { return len(h) }
    func (h IntHeap) Less(i, j int) bool { return h[i] < h[j] }
    func (h IntHeap) Swap(i, j int)      { h[i], h[j] = h[j], h[i] }
    
    func (h *IntHeap) Push(x interface{}) {
        // Push and Pop use pointer receivers because they modify the slice's length,
        // not just its contents.
        *h = append(*h, x.(int))
    }
    
    func (h *IntHeap) Pop() interface{} {
        old := *h
        n := len(old)
        x := old[n-1]
        *h = old[0 : n-1]
        return x
    }
    
    // This example inserts several ints into an IntHeap, checks the minimum,
    // and removes them in order of priority.
    func Example_intHeap() {
        h := &IntHeap{2, 1, 5}
        heap.Init(h)
        heap.Push(h, 3)
        fmt.Printf("minimum: %d\n", (*h)[0])
        for h.Len() > 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", heap.Pop(h))
        }
        // Output:
        // minimum: 1
        // 1 2 3 5
    }
```

Comment: Little bit explanation would be nicer.

Comment: added a tutorial here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDP1FCT6qZ4